# The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect when the types are the same

Tags: c#, linq

This has confused me, I have the title error on the join in the following LINQ:

```
var r = (from k in location.tblKeyAccountInfoes
                     join l in location.tblLocations
                     on new { k.MemberID, k.LocationID } equals
                     new {l.MemberId, l.LocationId }
                     where k.MemberID == memberid && k.UserName == username
                     select l.LocationName);

            return r.ToString();
```

However, the type for MemberId and LocationId is the same so I'm not sure what I have done wrong.

Any pointers gratefully received.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The types of MemberID and LocationID may be the same, but they have to have the same *name* as well.

In your example, one of them has **ID** (capital D) and the other has **Id** (lower-case d). That is enough to make the anonymous types separate types.

You can fix this by specifying names explicitly, for example:

```
 join l in location.tblLocations
 on new { k.MemberID, k.LocationID } equals
 new { MemberID = l.MemberId, LocationID = l.LocationId }
```

Comment: Ah right - boo!!! Nice update and does the trick - cheers Timwi, most appreciated and good explanation as well.